# networkx cannot import name 'create_degree_sequence'

Tags: python, networkx

Python library `networkx` has a function `create_degree_sequence`. It appears in several answers, such as this: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969892/814438).

I am using `networkx` version 2.6.3.

When I try to import the function, I get this error: `cannot import name 'create_degree_sequence' from 'networkx.utils'` I have not found where the function was moved to in the documentation. Is the function still available? Was it replaced with another function?

```
import networkx
from networkx.utils import powerlaw_sequence
from networkx.utils import create_degree_sequence

num = 100
exp = 2.5
sequence = create_degree_sequence(num, powerlaw_sequence, exponent=exp)
```

```
cannot import name 'create_degree_sequence' from 'networkx.utils'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969892/814438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this function seems to have been replaced. The latest equivalent is the [`configuration_model`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.configuration_model.html?highlight=configuration_model#networkx.generators.degree_seq.configuration_model) function, which can be imported with `from networkx import configuration_model`.